# How to make 2 buttons reference separate modal forms?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have 2 different contact buttons under 2 different price category. I am trying to make it so that each "Contact Us" button opens a modal form specific to that price category.

Here are my price boxes:

```
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="pricing hover-effect">
                <div class="pricing-head">
                    <h3>Device Testing <span>Great to track gas & electric meter tests, backflow tests and PM orders.</span></h3>
                    <h4><i>$</i>50<i></i> <span>/user/month</span></h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="pricing-content list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="icon-file-alt"></i> Ad-hoc order creation</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-list"></i> Device testing & inspection tracking</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-sitemap"></i> Track comments from the field</li>

                </ul>
                <div class="pricing-footer">
<!--                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut non libero magna psum olor .</p> -->
                    <a class="btn-u" href="meter" style="font-size:15px;"> I Want to Learn More</a> 
                    <div class="pricing-contact">
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">Contact Us</button>
                    </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
            <div class="pricing hover-effect">
                <div class="pricing-head">
                    <h3>Professional <span>Straightforward work order management, great for those currently tracking on paper.</span></h3>
                    <h4><i>$</i>75<i></i> <span>/user/month</span></h4>
                </div>
                <ul class="pricing-content list-unstyled">
                    <li><i class="icon-map-marker"></i> Work order mapping</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-off"></i> Equipment installs & transfers</li>
                    <li><i class="icon-comments"></i> Order assignment & dispatching</li>

                </ul>
                <div class="pricing-footer">
<!--                     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut non libero magna psum olor .</p> -->
                        <a class="btn-u" href="professional" style="font-size:15px;"> I Want to Learn More</a>                
                        <div id=pricing-contact>
                    <div class="pricing-contact">
                    <button a href="#professional" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-2" type="submit">Contact Us</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>                    
            </div>

        </div>
```

And the code I use to open the modal form is:

```
    <!-- Beginning of Pop-up Device Form -->

    <div class="btn-buy hover-effect" data-target="#modal-1" data-toggle=
    "modal"></div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="responsive" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type=
                    "button">×</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">SpryMobile Device
                    Testing</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <form>
                                <h4>Name</h4>

                                <p><input class="form-control" id="contactName"
                                name="contactName" type="text"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>Email Address</h4>

                            <p><input class="form-control" id="contactEmail"
                            name="contactEmail" type="email"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h4>Tell us about your operation</h4>
                            <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id=
                            "contactMessage" name="contactMessage" rows="7">
</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn-u btn-u-default" data-dismiss="modal"
                    type="button">Close</button> <button class="btn-u" id=
                    "contactSubmit" name="contactSubmit">Send Message <i class=
                    "icon-spinner icon-spin" id="contactSpinner" style=
                    "display:none;"></i></button>

                    <div class="alert alert-success" id="messageSuccess" style=
                    "display:none;">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type=
                        "button">x</button> <strong>Thank you!</strong> We
                        appreciate your comments, and will get back to you
                        soon.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of pop-up -->


    <!-- Beginning of Pop-up Professional Form -->

    <div class="btn-buy hover-effect" data-target="#modal-2" data-toggle=
    "modal"></div>

    <div class="modal fade" id="responsive" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type=
                    "button">×</button>

                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">SpryMobile
                    Professional</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <form>
                                <h4>Name</h4>

                                <p><input class="form-control" id="contactName"
                                name="contactName" type="text"></p>
                            </form>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <h4>Email Address</h4>

                            <p><input class="form-control" id="contactEmail"
                            name="contactEmail" type="email"></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <h4>Tell us about your operation</h4>
                            <textarea class="form-control" cols="20" id=
                            "contactMessage" name="contactMessage" rows="7">
</textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn-u btn-u-default" data-dismiss="modal"
                    type="button">Close</button> <button class="btn-u" id=
                    "contactSubmit" name="contactSubmit">Send Message <i class=
                    "icon-spinner icon-spin" id="contactSpinner" style=
                    "display:none;"></i></button>

                    <div class="alert alert-success" id="messageSuccess" style=
                    "display:none;">
                        <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" type=
                        "button">x</button> <strong>Thank you!</strong> We
                        appreciate your comments, and will get back to you
                        soon.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!-- End of pop-up -->
```

I tried adding the code for the modal form twice and then adding ids to reference them in the button section but I had no luck... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your `data-target` to be unique for each modal and match the id of the corresponding modal form.

Button to launch first modal:

```
            <div class="pricing-contact">
                <button data-target="#modal-1" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</button>
            </div>
```

First modal

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="modal-1" tabindex="-1">
            </div>
```

Button to launch second modal:

```
           <div class="pricing-contact">
                <button data-target="#modal-2" data-toggle="modal">Contact Us</button>
           </div>
```

Second modal

```
           <div class="modal fade" id="modal-2" tabindex="-1">
           </div>
```

And you don't need `type="submit"` in these buttons

Comment: I changed the data-targets but for some reason now the modal forms don't pop up at all. I have updated my question with the edits I made.

Comment: The data-targets now have to match the ids of the modals, I updated the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track adding code for another modal and the reference to the ids in the buttons section, however, were the ids *unique?*

Both modals cannot both be called "#responsive"

It's also better practice to use semantic names where possible, so consider using "#device1" and "#device2" as your two IDs.

This answer is kind of a shot in the dark but I hope it helps :)